# If else in AutoMapper ForMember

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map two different objects

```
CreateMap<A, B>()
  .ForMember(x => x.Quantity, y => y.MapFrom(z =>z.QuantityList.First().TotalQuantity))
```

I would like to assign `x.Quantity = 1 if z =>z.QuantityList.First().TotalQuantity == 0` othwerwise the above mapping.

How is this done in `ForMember()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options. You could wrap the if/else in a function, you can use an `if {}` block, but in this case the easiest way might be to use an inline ternary operator:

E.G:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt
    .MapFrom(src => (src.Quantitylist.First().TotalQuantity == 0) ? 1 
    : src.QuantityList.First().TotalQuantity))
```

Answer (score 6):

While you got already your answer with the ternary operator, I think there is something important to add:

You can always use a codeblock `{}` in your lambda*:

```
.MapFrom(src => {
    var quantity = src.Quantitylist.First().TotalQuantity;
    if (quantity == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return quantity;
})
```

In this case the ternary operator is fine, but if you need more advanced stuff, remember that there is another solution ;)

<sub>*excluding exotic linq providers like Linq2Sql/EF</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to show you how it could work. I've used a simple class structure. Think, yours has more detail. Also I used the newest version of AutoMapper.

```
class A
{
    public List<int> QuantityList { get; set; } = new List<int>();
}

class B
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

var a = new A();
a.QuantityList.Add(5);
Mapper.Initialize(c => c.CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(x => x.Quantity, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.QuantityList.First() == 0 ? 1 : z.QuantityList.First())));
var b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(a);
```